# ошибка при использовании команды pip

Tags: python, linux, debian, pip

Я получаю ошибку при использовании команды pip install colorama.

````
    from pip._internal import main                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>               from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning                                      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>                 vendored("colorama")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)                                              File "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/colorama/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/colorama/initialise.py", line 6, in <module>                                       File "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/colorama/winterm.py", line 2, in <module>                                          File "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/colorama/win32.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 556, in <module>
    _reset_cache()                                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 276, in _reset_cache                               CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError ```
````

Comment: Какая команда и где выдаёт такую ошибку?

Comment: Ошибку выдает команда pip на linux

Comment: Вы просто `pip` вводите в терминале?

Comment: pip пакет, пайтон установлен

Comment: Что pip пакет? Скопируйте в точности в вопрос команду или код, который выдаёт эту ошибку

Comment: pip install colorama

Comment: а место на жестком диске свободное есть?)

Comment: Да, его много, оперативка тоже не загружена полностью

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь. А для какой версии python Вы пытаетесь установить пакет?. Просто если для python 2+ то `pip`, а если для python 3+ то `pip3` как бы запускать нужно. И устанавливать pip для 3-ей версии нужно `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: Пробывал и для пайтон  2 и для пайтон 3, все равно выдает ошибку, даже просто команда pip --help вызывает ошибку (немного другую, но тоже ошибка памяти)

Comment: Какая версия python (полностью) у Вас установлена? (`python3 -V`) из документации на `colorama` - `"Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*"`

Answer (score 0):

У Вас не установлен pip или повредился при установке. Переустановите, предварительно освободив место: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip --upgrade` или для python не третьей версии :  `sudo apt-get install python-pip --upgrade`

Также проверьте, есть ли python и python/scripts в PATH (`echo $PATH`)и если не - добавьте (`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python3` и `PATH=”$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python3/scripts`)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110856/discussion-on-answer-by-nezerix-----pip).

Comment: Не помогло все та же ошибка

Comment: @pavelFramer Проверьте версию python, как писали в комментариях к вопросу

Comment: Версия python 3.7.3